# confused about python looping

Tags: python

I'm confused about the iteration process in python

I have:

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in numbers:
    v = numbers
    print v
```

Here is the end of loop
but, in C , C++ , Java we know the line inside the `{ }` will be executed repeatedly, or if not given curly braces then the next statement after the loop, but I'm confused here.
How many lines will be executed in the iteration? 
Does it depend on indent?

Comment: i'm really new in Pyhon ! but have another programming language knowledge ,

Comment: You should probably read the tutorial. Yes it depends on the indentation.

Comment: This is a pretty basic question, maybe you could have answered that just by reading some lines in the Python tutorial, as someone already said.

Comment: Try something like Dive Into Python. http://www.diveintopython.net

Comment: You can find the tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) or [here](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), for Python2 and Python3, respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, the indentation, rather than brackets, determines block scope, so in this example both the indented lines will be executed once per iteration of the loop.

This is the single weirdest thing about Python for programmers coming from the C/Java language families, but you get used to it fairly quickly.

Comment: If that's the most unusual thing about Python to you, you haven't dived in very deeply :-)

Comment: @delnan: I wonder, what is the weirdest thing for C/Java programmers in your opinion. Sorry for being slightly off topic, but curiosity prevailed.

Comment: i's watching videos and it's done on their , not learning from any tutorial ,and searched google for that ,
and got nothing to learn about it ! :(

Comment: Well, I was mainly speaking of the initial impressions. What are you thinking of?

Comment: There are numerous things, and they depend on the individual programmer and the exact languages s/he used before. Some examples: Classes are first-class objects (can be created at any time, passed around, stored in variables, etc.), context managers (`with` statement), generators, coroutines, runtime code generation/metaprogramming (`exec` and such).

Answer (score 4):

Python uses indents to separate blocks of code. Try to think about this specific code as:

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in numbers:  #{
    v = numbers
    print v
#}
```

This is completely valid Python code that has comments with curly braces where you would expect them in some different languages.

Python's counterpart of executing single statement is:

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in numbers: v = numbers
print v
```

and every loop will execute only `v = numbers` (by using `;` you can add statements in the same line, however).

Comment: ok. thanks , 
and i'm watching videos of 2.7 and coding on 3.3 IDE 
and causing some syntax errors. 
can you please tell me which one of 2.7 or 3.3 will be better in learning and implementing .

Comment: @Sirajul_Islam: Learn 3.3, its popularity is rising. 2.7 is not much different and much more popular in business applications (due to whole ecosystem of modules that do not support 3.x). Some significant features from 3.x line were backported in the 2.6 and 2.7 releases.

Comment: @Sirajul_Islam - I second that. Python 3.3 is the future. Many features have been added to it to improve it over Python 2.7, making things more uniform (behave alike) and making it better to program with. After you become more comfortable with Python 3.3, **then** you can go back and learn about what is different in 2.7

Comment: tnx for your suggestion , 
i got raw_input() is missing in 3.3 and replaced with input()
while the print in transferred to print() like as java's print function .. 
but having conflictions with data type ..

Comment: @Tadeck __ if i use print v; 
and then use semi-colon, 
will that be the last line of the block? 
if yes, then , isn't it safer than using without semi-colons?

Comment: @Sirajul_Islam - you don't need to use semi-colons in Python. You end a block by changing your indentation back out.

Comment: ya , i know ! but i said anything else
hope you din't get that !

Comment: @Sirajul_Islam: 1) The safer solution is to use indents. 2) About `raw_input()` issue: you can use [`six` module](http://pythonhosted.org/six/), which has multiple compatibility solutions, like [`six.input` function](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves), which works as Python 2.x's `raw_input()` and Python 3.x's `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

In python, indentation matters a lot. In your code, both of these lines will get executed in each iteration of the for loop:

```
   v = numbers
   print v
```

Comment: ya, that means if the indent is missing for any reason may occur some errors? 
and 
which will be better in learning and implementing 
i'm watching video of 2.7 and installed 3.3 of Python !

Comment: yep, you may get some errors or your code will not do the desired job.

Comment: IMO learning python3 is better, since it's newer than python2.Though  I've not learnt Python2.

Comment: Learning Python 3 is better because Python 3 is better. Age/Youth is not an accomplishment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an additional note, I think your original code is not doing what I think you want it to do - which is print the numbers 1-5 on their own line. It should be (using Python 3):

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in numbers:
    print(i)
```

If you run the following code:

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
v = numbers
print(v)
```

you'll get:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @Sirajul_Islam - did your question get answered?

Comment: mmhmm. 
ya . got the answers , and thanks for your extra help , and it'll help me too  . cause i'm really too new in Python ! :)

Comment: @Sirajul_Islam - don't worry - we all have to start somewhere! I'm fairly new myself, and a lot of my learning has involved where to find answers to your questions. The [Python 3 Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), the [documentation itself](http://docs.python.org/3/), and of course StackOverflow are all great resources. For books, I really liked [Head First Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920003434.do), and there's an updated 2nd ed. coming in July.